# Azure DevOps - Inherit Development Links from Child to Parent work items

Tags: azure-devops

After reading through the [End-to-End traceability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cross-service/end-to-end-traceability?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) documentation our team is finding it difficult to accomplish the final step in this list:

1. Developers create a branch or PR on a work item (in this case, a Task)
2. When the PR is completed and the branch merged, the work item shows the build
3. When the build artifact is released, the work item shows the deployment environments

All of that works great, but the final step is:

4. Show the builds and deployments on all parent tasks of the work item i.e., the Feature work item and the User Story work item.

Is that not possible? Or is there a rule or template that we could write that would automatically copy development links up the hierarchical chain so that developers and business can see the traceability across all associated work items?

Conversely, are we intended to manually link all development links to all work items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you want parent work items to display builds and deployments tracked by child work items.

Testing on my side, the parent work items will not show the builds and deployments tracked by the child work items. DevOps currently does not support such feature.

We recommend that you could request this feature on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.